# max file upload size change in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, web-config, maxlength

using .net mvc 3 and trying to increase the allowable file upload size.

This is what I've added to web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

*ignore the elmah stuff.

it's still not allowing file sizes larger than 50MB and this should allow up to 100MB no?

any ideas?

Comment: set maxRequestLength, detail in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: AFAIK, fileuploads are base 64 encoded, so the bytestream may be 8/6 of the file size.

Answer (score 3):

In case other people stumble across this later on, you can also set a max file size for specific routes. This is what I have in my one project.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- This will allow this setting only for this one action method. -->
    <location path="Attachment/HandleUpload">
        <system.web>
            <!-- I needed to set for 20 MB. -->
            <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480"/>
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <!-- other configuration settings here, including appSettings -->
</configuration>
```